# how to let Powerpoint remember the macro command shortcut in customize ribbon

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wrote some macro with powerpoint 2013, and I add the shortcut of these macro command to customize ribbon, afer I set these macro shortcut up, they are working, but after I restart the computer, these macro shortcut no work anymore?
What is the reason, any better way to set a shortcut of macro in Powerpoint

Comment: Have you tried to change the Macro security level? You can do so in the Trust center.

Comment: Yes, I did, I  set the trust center-macro settings -enable all macros  and trust access to the  VBA project object model,  But the macro command shortcut in customize ribbon only work after they just added, after you restart computer they will not work again.

Comment: It shows : the specific value is out of range.  oshp.PictureFormat.CropTop = 0.5 * 72 shows yellow